# I want to join two tables and display two rows as a single row

Tags: sql-server

I want something like:

**Particulars**         **Info**

Abc                    1,2,3

instead  of :

**Particulars**         **Info**

Abc                    1

Abc                    2

Abc                    3

Comment: What have you tried so far. Can you provide a Minimal Complete Verifyable Example of what you tried? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use groupconcat

**Reference given below::**

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: ?!?!? how can it work in sql-server? this solution is for mysql

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution for sql-server

```
select Particulars, stuff((
    select ',' + cast(Info as varchar(20))
    from YourTable b
    where a.Particulars = b.Particulars
    for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as Info
from YourTable a group by Particulars
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2017, you can use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get your expected result.

```
SELECT Particulars, STRING_AGG (Info, ',') AS Info
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY Particulars;
```